# Bootstrap cannot center text horizontally within column inside centered row

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am building a form, I have a row that I need to center both horizontally an vertically, but I also need to have the text of the first column right-aligned (the first column holds the labels that must appear on the left-side of the inputs). Here is the code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
            <label for="numberOfPeople">Number of people</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="p-inputgroup">
                <p-inputNumber inputId="numberOfPeople" [(ngModel)]="numberOfPeople"> </p-inputNumber>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the text of the first column keeps being centered. I've tried putting the `.text-right` class on the label, and even replacing the label with a `p`  tag but without success. It's been so many years since I haven't used bootstrap, I want to use its semantic classes to achieve this but I am struggling. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Bootstrap are you using? Bootstrap v5 "[Renamed several utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#utilities-3) to use logical property names instead of directional names." Therefore, you'd want to use the class `text-end` instead of `text-right` when using v5.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
            <label for="numberOfPeople">Number of people</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="p-inputgroup">
                <p-inputNumber inputId="numberOfPeople" [(ngModel)]="numberOfPeople"> </p-inputNumber>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! It looks like I got confused and was referring to an outdated version of the documentation